# Creating box plots with rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

Is it possible to draw box plots using the rCharts package? I've not been able to find documentation on the allowable inputs to the `type` parameter in the `rPlot` function (which is the polychart library). I've tried 'boxplot, 'boxPlot', bwPlot'...

**Edit:** 
searching through the javascript it looks like only the hPlot (highcharts) library supports boxplots, is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Polycharts does support `boxplots`, but they look ugly by default :)

```
data(tips, package = 'reshape2')
p3 <- rPlot(x = 'day', y = 'box(tip)', data = tips, type = 'box')
p3
```

You might need to tweak a few options on the width of the box lines to make it prettier and bring it up to ggplot2 standards.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: why the box() for the y-axis?